# Integral of $\sin{x} (1 + 2 \cos{x})^4$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I'm looking for a way to solve

> $$ \int{ \sin{x} \, ( 1 + 2 \cos{x})^4 }. $$

I think there are some theorems which help me but right now I don't know how to do it. I know that $$ 1 = \cos^2{x} + \sin^2{x} $$  but I don't know how to apply it. I think this must be another tricky one.

Comment: Maple can help you: take a look at [that link](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/Calculus1SingleStepping). However, in your case the IntTutor command suggests to expand the integrand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Substitute  $1+2\cos x=u$

Comment: okay. try that and come back later :).

Comment: Okay i have integral sin x * u^4 - du/2 * sin x now. How do I proceed?

Comment: @DominiqueLüber, if $1+2\cos x=u, -2\sin x dx=du$ and $\int{ \sin{x} \, ( 1 + 2 \cos{x})^4 }=\int u^4(\frac{-du}2)=-\frac12\cdot\frac{u^5}5+K$

Comment: the derivative of 1 + 2 cos x is -2 sin x?! you are missing a 2 here? $ du = - 2 \sin{x} $!

Comment: so its * dx not just dx? that means i plugin * du/(2*sin x) .. maybe that was my fault

Comment: @DominiqueLüber, sorry for the mistake. Rectified the comment. Btw, have you followed the method?

Comment: Okay. Everything's clear now. Solved! Wondering why wolframalpha comes up with a complete different solution

Comment: @DominiqueLüber, What is their solution

Comment: I dont know. Something weird and long

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\int{ \sin x ( 1 + 2 \cos{x})^4 } dx = -\int{ (1 + 2 \cos{x})^4 } d(\cos x).$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$ \int f^n(x) f'(x)dx  =  \frac{f^{n+1}(x)}{n+1} +c $$

Comment: I dont get that.

Comment: @DominiqueLüber: To see that, assume $u=f(x)$ and work out the integral and things will be clear. Note that, in your case $f(x)= 1 + 2 \cos{x}$.

Comment: @DominiqueLüber: if you put $u=f(x) \implies du=f'(x) dx$, now subs back in the integral and see what you get.

Comment: I wrote that in another comment in this thread here. I got $ \int \sin{x} * u^4 - \frac{du}{2*\sin{x}} $

Comment: @DominiqueLüber, you can **not** substitute *and* then leave the same variable! If $\;u=\cos x\;$ then  $$\;du=-\sin x\,dx=-\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}dx=\sqrt{1-u^2}dx\implies dx=\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\ldots$$

Comment: @DonAntonio do I need that part? sin x cancels out?!

Comment: Oh, I know that @DominiqueLüber ... My comment is in the general case, not in this particular case.

Comment: Yeah. Everytime my x does not get canceled out, i need to express all x through u right? that is what you mean

Comment: @DominiqueLüber: Yes, you are right.